# Why use comparable and comparator interface

Tags: java, collections

I recently faced and interview where they asked me a question. Why use comparable and comparator interface in java to sort elements of a collection. Why not use a bubble sort directly instead. Forgive me if it is my ignorance, but still give me an answer.

Comment: Well, how would you write a bubble sort that handles both a `List<Integer>` and a `List<String>` for example? You could write each one separately, but fundamentally you're going to need to compare the elements of the collection each time... and that "I can compare any two elements in the collection" is precisely what the interfaces are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question such as "why use `Comparator` or `Comparable` rather than bubble sort?" really makes no sense. These are not alternatives to each other. Any sorting algorithm (including ones that you code yourself) needs a mechanism for defining the order of the objects. That is what the interfaces do: provide a mechanism for defining an ordering on objects.

If the question is "why use sorting methods built into the JDK rather than write your own?" then the answer is probably fairly obvious: it saves effort and complexity.

If the question is "when should you use `Comparable` and when should you use `Comparator`?" then I would suggest searching for one of the excellent primers on this topic. As a very simplified answer, `Comparable` is used to define a natural (default) ordering for objects within a class while `Comparator` is used to define a custom ordering to be passed to a method.

Note also that the `Comparator` interface has many very powerful methods for defining comparisons. Very little needs to be done manually now. For example, if you have a `Person` class you can sort a list with code such as:

```
Collection.sort(personList, Comparator
    .comparingInt(Person::getAge)
    .thenComparing(Person::getSurname));
```

In my view this code is better than the old mechanism of defining `compareTo` methods in a class as it hides away the implementation details of returning arbitrary integers representing comparison between fields and makes the intention pretty obvious. In fact it's enough of an improvement on older methods that in my own code I tend to avoid natural orderings altogether unless the class has an inherent obvious order that can be naturally represented as the difference between two integers (e.g. a class defining temperature or heights).

Comment: does the Person class needs to implement Comparable?

Comment: @gaurav No. Implementing comparable would only be necessary if you wanted to define a natural ordering for Person and not provide your own Comparator. In the code snippet I gave there's not need for a natural ordering.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that this is a bit of trick question designed to expose one's knowledge of certain fundamental concepts in the Java language.

A little about `Comparable` and `Comparator`.  See [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)

> The `Comparable` interface imposes the [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) of an object,
>   through contract of the `compareTo()` method.
>
> The `Comparator` interface imposes the [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) of objects on
>   some collection of objects, through contract of the `compare()`
>   method.
>
> The `Arrays.sort(objectArray)` method only works with a collection of
>   objects that implement the `Comparable` interface, i.e. have natural
>   ordering.

[Stack Post Explaining Total Order vs. Natural Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176643/difference-between-natural-ordering-and-total-ordering)

If you think about it, if any class implements the `Comparable` interface then any collection of it's objects can be sorted using `Collection.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`.  Any Object will be sorted on the basis of the `compareTo` method in that class.  So, why use a bubble sort?   `Arrays.sort()` uses a `quicksort`, `dual-pivot quicksort`, `mergesort`, or `timsort` accordingly.

A quick look at the [Big-O Cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) reveals
[image]

Notice the `bubble sort` time.  Do you want to use a `bubble sort` in a worst-case scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorting algorithm of your choice e.g. bubble, insertion, quicksort with your comparator. It is never a choice between a Comparator implementation and a sorting algorithm.

For elements that have natural ordering e.g. numbers, strings in a lexical order, a comparator is not required if that order works for you.

What would you do for custom objects or data types that you design? How would you sort two `Car` objects, two `Person` objects, two complex numbers and so on? That is where a comparator comes handy e.g. you can sort a Car based on length, weight, etc that you specify in the comparator.