# Binary search tree comparing one node type string with another

Tags: java, nodes

I am studying Binary Search Tree data structure and I have an issue when trying to compare two string nodes. This is my code, on the 18th line down I want to compare the root node and another string node.

```
nodeToAdd.word < node.word //this is how i want to compare the nodes
```

I know you cant use `<` or `>` when comparing strings and you would use `compareTo()` or `equals()`. In this situation when comparing nodes, how would I compare the two nodes to see which node is alphabetically higher or lower?

```
public class binarytree implements WordStore {

    Node root;

    public void add(String word) {
        Node nodeToAdd = new Node(word);

        if (root == null) {
            // if there's no root, then the node becomes root

            root = nodeToAdd;
        }
        traverseAdd(root, nodeToAdd);

    }
    private void traverseAdd(Node node, Node nodeToAdd) {

        if (nodeToAdd.word < node.word)) {
            if (node.leftChild == null) {
                node.leftChild = nodeToAdd;
            } else {
                traverseAdd(node.leftChild, nodeToAdd);
            }
     //more code not relevant....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two nodes, define a `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<Node> nodeComparer = Comparator.comparing(node -> node.word);
```

Now to compare two nodes you can use:

```
nodeCompare.compare(node1, node2);
```

Don't implement `Comparable` on a class unless there is a natural ordering for that class that will be sensible in most situations (sorting, finding smallest, largest etc). I don't think this is true for nodes. I can imagine wanting to sort by depth in the tree, or number of decendents or find the node with the longest string or some other criteria. Better to use a custom `Comparator` that suits your need.

Also note that if you implement `Comparable` you likely should define `equals` and `hashCode` as well because the natural order is strongly recommended to be consistent with equals (see [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)).

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176643/difference-between-natural-ordering-and-total-ordering) for more information on natural ordering and when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have class `Node` implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and by that you'll have to override the method [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) in which you can compare strings alphabetically.

You can delegate the comparison to the words that the nodes hold by doing something like: `return this.word.compareTo(Other.word)`

Comment: Is there any other way or is this the best code practise?

Comment: @Timmay696969 this is the object oriented way: you want to be able to compare nodes, have the class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: @Timmay696969 This is the standard way, and it makes the Node class sortable by the collections framework. However, you could define a `greaterThan()` method on Node to capture this concept, but I wouldn't.