# Complex Comparators in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator, type-inference

Can some one explain the difference between following variants of complex `Comparator`s?

```
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("algo", "test", "is", "a", "common");

listOfStrings.stream()
             .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
             .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder().thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Why first call of `sorted` is OK, while second one can not even compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler knows that `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)` returns a `Comparator<String>` (since you are passing a `ToIntFunction<String>` to it), and therefore expects the second `Comparator`, passed to `thenComparing`, to be a `Comparator<String>`, so it can infer the type of the `Comparator` returned by `Comparator.naturalOrder()` to be a `Comparator<String>`.

On the other hand, when the first `Comparator` is returned by `Comparator.naturalOrder()` (which returns a `Comparator<T>`), the compiler doesn't know which type of `Comparator` to expect for the argument of `thenComparing`, so it rejects the `Comparator<String>` passed to it.

This error can be avoided if you declare the type of the `Comparator` returned by `Comparator.naturalOrder()` explicitly:

```
Comparator<String> comp = Comparator.naturalOrder();
listOfStrings.stream()
             .sorted(comp.thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or just `.sorted(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().thenComparingInt(String::length))`…

Answer (score 2):

1. comparingInt(ToIntFunction keyExtractor)

Accepts a function that extracts an int sort key from a type T, and returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key.

2. naturalOrder()

Returns a comparator that compares Comparable objects in natural order.

You can check natural order from there;
[difference between natural ordering and total ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176643/difference-between-natural-ordering-and-total-ordering)

Comparator API;
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--

Comment: How does this answer why one `sorted` call passed compilation and the other doesn't?