# How the map entries are ordered in this priority queue?

Tags: java, queue, comparator

what's the comparator used in this priorityqueue?

```
        PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
                (a, b) ->
            b.getValue() - a.getValue()
```

Is it sorting the queue according to the descending order of the values in this map?

Comment: Why not try to run the code and find out the order direction? Best not to use the site as a substitute for any tutorial on the subject as well as your own Java compiler and JVM.

Comment: The map entries are ordered in the priority queue by their values.  The largest value will be at the front of the queue.

Comment: And this is the comparator: `(a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue()`

Comment: and the queue *itself* is not ordered

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels _Why not try to run the code and find out_.     >> Probably not a very good advice for computer science.

Comment: Please Read the Manual/Documentation before asking basic questions here.
From [Priority Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) - "_The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used._"

Comment: To read more about Natural Order, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176643/difference-between-natural-ordering-and-total-ordering)..
In short, Natural Order is something that depends on the default implementaion of that type in JVM.. for example, for characters object - it will be their unicode values, for numbers natural order is ascending order..

Comment: @Tintin: one key to understanding priority queues, is that the collection *itself* is not ordered: any iterator obtained will *not* traverse the queue in any order, and will not respect either "natural" order or comparator order. To get the items in order, either pass it into an array list and sort it, or use remove to remove the head of the queue, which *is* in priority order.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - yes, a good reminder.

Comment: From the same link posted above [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  "_The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())_"

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is sorted according to the descending order of the values in this map.